# Create tree stucture url in php using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, friendly-url

I started learning basics of `.htaccess` file and here i wanted to know how can i create tree stucture url in php using `.htaccess` file. For example, I have hierarchy like :- **science->biology->zoology->dermatology**. and domain is **www.mydomain.com**. So

If I click on **science**, Url should be **www.mydomain.com/science**.

Under science If I click on **biology**, Url should be **www.mydomain.com/science/biology**.

Under biology If I click on **zoology**, Url should be **www.mydomain.com/science/biology/zoology**. and so on.

Here is what I tried so far, created a page called as `branch.php`, If i click on science i am writing code in `branch.php` file by using url **www.mydomain.com/branch/science** and htacces file

```html
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^branch/(.*) branch.php?branch_name=$1 [L]
```

So I can i create url like **www.mydomain.com/science/biology/zoology** without creating page(branch.php) using `.htacces` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a little disorientation in your thoughts.

Any kind of url you are generating in the `PHP` without any restrictions.

And `.htaccess` (and `mod_rewrite` in particular) used only for redirection of request (transparent for users) to the particular php-file.

So, yes, you can do url like this: `http://www.example.com/science/biology/zoology` and your `.htacces` should be like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* branch.php [L]
```

Then, in the `branch.php` you should examine `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` (it will look like this `/science/biology/zoology`) and make a decision what to show to the user.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is needed to test that requested uri didn't point to real file.

---

**UPDATE:** If you want to use `$_GET` array in the `branch.php` you can do the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ branch.php?main_branch=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ branch.php?main_branch=$1&sub_branch=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ branch.php?main_branch=$1&sub_branch=$2&sub2_branch=$3 [L]
```

Comment: But i dont want to show branch.php keyword(file name) in url, Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Take a closer look, in my answer there is no `branch` keyword in the url.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer , Let me to try this and let you know.

Comment: Hi spirite, As of i know $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] will hold the full request path including the querystring, So is it possible to use GET method , for example like $main_branch = $_GET['main_branch'], $sub_branch = $_GET['sub_branch'] and so on ?

Comment: Thank you spirite.